Windows 11 on ARM64, how to upgrade from 21H2 to 23H2?
I have a Windows 11 virtual machine on ARM64 platform, with a fully registered digital license.
It is currently Windows 11 21H2 (was installed for testing quite some time ago) and I would like to update it to the latest version, meaning 23H2 I suppose.
All online resources say that the update should be available through "Windows Update", possibly in "optional updates" category. But it is not. I get the latest updates for 21H2 but nothing for 22H2 or 23H2. There is zero optional update.
On Intel platforms, this is how it works. But it does not seem to be the case on ARM64.
I don't see any downloadable full update ISO either.
Any idea ?
